# How identify that form is consuming a Data Service

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a C# WinForms application with using of WCF Data Services and I can't find a way to know if the application is doing a process to a web service. I have tried to implement IClientMessageInspector, etc. but it seems that it doesn't work.

Is there any other way to catch when a Windows Form app is consuming a web service? The purpose is to display a "running process" icon when the communication to a service is opened and then hide it when it's close.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should add event in place where you calling WcfService methods and then listen to this event in UI layer. With custom event argument in this event, you should provide more info for consuming UI layer like enum values Connected, TransferStarted, TransferEnded, Closed,...

I think there are two main possible cases:
Wcf communication take place synchronous - you are calling some wrapper methods of object which handles connection/requests/responses with wcf service - in this case i think its trivial, you make UI actions before every call of wrapper for example

```
try
{
 WcfEx.IwcfS5ExtensionClient client = new IwcfS5ExtensionClient("MyEndpointConfigurationName");
 client.Open();
 if (client.State == CommunicationState.Opened)
 {
     //change UI to Connected
 }
 else
 {
     //change ui to Connection Error
 }
 Application.DoEvents();
 //Change UI to Transfering data
 Application.DoEvents();
 client.DoWork();
 //change UI to transfer done
 Application.DoEvents();
 client.Close();
 //change ui to Closed
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   //change ui to Comunication error
}
```

Second is if wcf communication is async
-i will add more sofisticated sample later today
EDIT: Example with async work and notifying form

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

using WcfEx;

public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        WcfHandler WcfConnection = new WcfHandler();
        WcfConnection.ProgressChanged += WcfConnectionOnProgressChanged;
    }

    private delegate void WcfConnectionOnProgressChangedDelegate(object Sender, WcfHandler.ProgressChangedEventArgs EventArgs);

    private void WcfConnectionOnProgressChanged(object Sender, WcfHandler.ProgressChangedEventArgs EventArgs)
    {
        //multi thread synchronization check
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            object[] Parameters = new object[2];
            Parameters[0] = Sender;
            Parameters[1] = EventArgs;
            this.Invoke(new WcfConnectionOnProgressChangedDelegate(WcfConnectionOnProgressChanged), Parameters);
        }
        else
        {
            if (EventArgs == null)
                return;

            switch (EventArgs.StateValue)
            {
                case WcfHandler.ProgressChangedEventArgs.State.Started:
                    {
                        this.Text = "Starting connection...";
                        break;
                    }
                case WcfHandler.ProgressChangedEventArgs.State.Processing:
                    {
                        this.Text = "Downloading updates...";
                        break;
                    }
                case WcfHandler.ProgressChangedEventArgs.State.Finished:
                    {
                        this.Text = EventArgs.Succes ? "Update completed" : "Update failed";
                        break;
                    }
            }

            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }


    public class WcfHandler
    {
        public class ProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public enum State : int
            {
                Started,
                Processing,
                Finished
            };

            public bool Succes { get; set; }
            public State StateValue { get; set; }
        }

        public delegate void ProgressChangedEventHandler(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs EventArgs);

        public event ProgressChangedEventHandler ProgressChanged;

        protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ProgressChanged != null)
            {
                ProgressChanged(this, e);
            }
        }

        public void StartChecking()
        {
            BackgroundWorker bWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

            bWorker.DoWork += CheckStatesAsync;
            bWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BWorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted;

            bWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void CheckStatesAsync(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                WcfEx.IwcfS5ExtensionClient client = new IwcfS5ExtensionClient("MyWcfBindingConfig");
                ProgressChangedEventArgs Controller = new ProgressChangedEventArgs();
                Controller.StateValue = ProgressChangedEventArgs.State.Started;
                Controller.Succes = true;

                this.OnProgressChanged(Controller);

                try
                {
                    client.Open();

                    Controller.StateValue = ProgressChangedEventArgs.State.Processing;
                    Controller.Succes = true;
                    this.OnProgressChanged(Controller);

                    //do some work
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    this.OnProgressChanged(new ProgressChangedEventArgs()
                                               {
                                                   StateValue = ProgressChangedEventArgs.State.Finished,
                                                   Succes = false
                                               });
                }

                Thread.Sleep(8000);
            }
        }

        private void BWorkerOnRunWorkerCompleted(object Sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
        {
            ProgressChangedEventArgs Controller = new ProgressChangedEventArgs();
            Controller.StateValue = ProgressChangedEventArgs.State.Finished;
            Controller.Succes = true;
            this.OnProgressChanged(Controller);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any example I can see? Thanks a lot